# Why does Async Await work with React setState?

Tags: reactjs, async-await, babeljs

I have been using async await with babel in my ReactJS project. I discovered a convenient use with React setState that I would just like to understand better. Consider this code:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
  console.log('synchronous code')
}

changeAndValidate = async (e) => {
  await this.handleChange(e)
  console.log('asynchronous validation code')
}

componentDidUpdate() {
  console.log('updated component')    
}
```

My intention was for the asynchronous validation code to run after the component has updated. And it works! The resulting console log shows:

```
synchronous code
updated component
asynchronous validation code
```

The validation code will only run after handleChange has updated the state and the new state is rendered.

Usually to run code after state has updated, you would have to use a callback after this.setState. Which means if you want to run anything after handleChange, you have to give it a callback parameter which is then passed to setState. Not pretty. But in the code example, somehow await knows that handleChange is complete after the state has updated... But I thought await only works with promises and waits for a promise to resolve before continuing. Theres no promise and no resolution in handleChange... How does it know what to wait for??

The implication seems to be that setState is run asynchronously and await is somehow aware of when it completes. Maybe setState uses promises internally?

Versions:

react: "^15.4.2"

babel-core: "^6.26.0"

babel-preset-env: "^1.6.0",

babel-preset-react: "^6.24.1",

babel-preset-stage-0: "^6.24.1"

babel-plugin-system-import-transformer: "^3.1.0",

babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy: "^1.3.4",

babel-plugin-transform-runtime: "^6.23.0"

Comment: The code above has an `await` on `undefined` (because `handleChange` doesn't return anything). Are you sure it is having an effect on `setState`?

Comment: what version of React and babel are you using?

Comment: that's weird, but i confirm await **have effect**. `await this.setState({ data: true }, () => console.log('callback'));
    console.log('inline');`  clearly says `callback` will be fired first, however - remove await and works as usually setState suppose to work - `inline` first and then `callback`

Comment: @DavinTryon seems to be correct, you should turn it into an answer it would be helpful for others in the future as well as this is a pretty common search

Comment: I would like some elaboration too. Is the undefined returned by setState asynchronous? Does it always return after the component updates?

Comment: What happens if you remove the await from the above code? I expect it will behave exactly the same way - you're running this code synchronously, await or no.

Comment: No, if you remove the await, you will get synchronous code, asynchronous validation code, then lastly the updated component

Comment: probably the same as using a `setTimeout` with no time, it places its execution at the end of the event loop. Search online for `setTimeout no time` or similar.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

### I tried to do my best to simplify and complement Davin's answer, so you can get a better idea of what is actually going on here:

---

1. **await** is placed in front of **this.handleChange**, this will **schedule** the execution of the rest of **changeAndValidate** function to only run when **await** **resolves** the value specified to the right of it, in this case the value returned by **this.handleChange**
2. **this.handleChange**, on the right of **await**, executes:

   2.1. **setState** runs its updater but because **setState** does not guarantee to update immediately it potentially schedules the update to happen at a later time ***(it doesn't matter if it's immediate or at a later point in time, all that matters is that it's scheduled)***

   2.2. console.log('synchronous code') runs...

   2.3. **this.handleChange** then exits returning **undefined** *(returns undefined because functions return undefined unless explicitly specified otherwise)*
3. **await** then takes this **undefined** and since it's not a promise it converts it into a resolved promise, using **Promise.resolve(undefined)** and waits for it - it's not immediately available because behind the scenes it gets passed to its **.then** method which is asynchronous:

> “Callbacks passed into a promise will never be called before the
>   completion of the current run of the JavaScript event loop”

3.1. this means that **undefined** will get placed into the back of the **event queue**, *(which means it’s now behind our setState updater in the event queue…)*

4. **event loop** finally reaches and picks up our **setState** update, which now executes...
5. **event loop** reaches and picks up **undefined**, which evaluates to **undefined** *(we could store this if we wanted, hence the = commonly used in front of await to store the resolved result)*

   5.1. **Promise.resolve()** is now finished, which means **await** is no longer in affect, so the rest of the function can resume
6. your **validation** code runs

Comment: Will undefined returning reliably be placed behind the setState update in the event loop?

Comment: I'm not sure, it depends on the updating algorithm used, can't find enough information on it, however, if algorithm batches updates and runs them at the end of the current cycle of the event loop then it should be guaranteed

Comment: So it's just luck! :D

Answer (score 5):

I haven't tested this yet, but here is what I think is happening:

The `undefined` returned by `await` is queued after the `setState` callback. The `await` is doing a `Promise.resolve` underneath (in the `regenerator-runtime`) which in turn yields control to the next item on the event loop.

So, it is coincidence that the `setState` callback happens to be queued ahead of the `await`.

You can test this by putting a setTimeout(f => f, 0) around the `setState`.

`regenerator-runtime` in `babel` is essentially a loop that uses `Promise.resolve` to yield control. You can see the inside the [_asyncToGenerator](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=FAYw9gdgzgLgBACwIYQCYBsCmBhZEDmmcAvHABSYCUJAfHAN7BxwwICWUAdFJjAMowkMTGXoBtTJ0EAnQjE4QkAW0wBdAFxxJMuZwBuSdAFdMAX0pM44aGCyd0YfGQDkUAJ4QQCaZDBGoVmComM4WpsCgkLBWeIQAgmgAaoZsqEJEpEjunuRUtAyWSADuSGzwrByceBg4sSJUltZQtpIOTs5ZHl4-EH4BBuipQmyQgcGhwOHAAGZGnjAjEIFKAA6QmBAwACKpAKoracJk1IzMTS32ji5GB-moy2sQGzChzMyTQA&debug=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Cstage-0&targets=&version=6.26.0), it has a `Promise.resolve`.

Comment: The setTimeout does break it, but that is to be expected. Put a setTimeout around any promise and it will break async await wont it? But if setState acts like a promise in async await in every other situation, then this is still a viable pattern no?

Comment: @LeoFabrikant `setState` is not acting like a promise.  `await` is just getting queued after the `setState` callback.  There is only one event loop.

Comment: I mean, when would await get queued before the setState callback?

Comment: It depends on how/when the `setState` callback is queued relative to the return of `await`.  But using `await` with `regenerator` generates a lot of code that fundamentally changes the async flow (but hopefully not the behaviour).

Comment: I dont fully understand because I haven't fully grokked the event loop and how events get queued, but this seems to be the logical explanation

Answer (score 4):

> `setState()` does not always immediately update the component [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

But it may be the case here.

If you want to replace the callback with a promise you can implement it yourself :

```
setStateAsync(state) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    this.setState(state, resolve)
  });
}

handleChange = (e) => {
  return this.setStateAsync({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
}
```

ref : https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/async-await-with-react-lifecycle-methods-802e7760d802

Comment: Im not looking to change anything, the code works. Check out Vlad's comment under my post, or try it out with your own console logs. Any code following the await is paused and run only after this.setState has finished updating!

Comment: Maybe because it's immediately updated, and doesn't work when it's not the case.

Comment: I see what you're saying, that my method might not work when setState decides to wait. Might be a good idea to test that. But setState is still exhibiting strange behavior. I will add another example in the original to demonstrate this.

Comment: `it's not properly waiting for setState to complete. Your app just happens to finish setState quickly in that case, but will not for all cases` [ref](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2642#issuecomment-309027958)

Comment: @Gabriel your naming setStateAsync is rather confusing... isn't setState already async ? Would your function be better named setStateSync, as the intention here is to make it look sync.

Comment: @joe how a function returning a promise is supposed to be sync? setState is sometimes sync and sometimes async, the intent here is to make it async all the time.

Comment: @Gabriel.. ok my misunderstanding of promises. But i think in your example you need to resolve the promise in the setState callback by calling the resolve() - i.e. brackets required.

Answer (score 1):

The `rv` or return value of await is defined as:

```
rv
Returns the fulfilled value of the promise, or the value itself if it's not a Promise.
```

So since handleChange is not an async or promise value, it's simply returning the natural value (in this case, there is no return, so `undefined`). Thus, there is no async event loop trigger here to "let it know handleChange is done", it simply just runs in the order you have given it.

Comment: You would think that would happen. But thats not what happens. Await pauses the code until the setState has finished... Then runs whatever follows inline. Try it out with console logs

Comment: I agree. Just put an alert attached to a state that alerts in the render function and you will see.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Take a simple example： in the `test-02`, the code `await this.setState({ a: 10 });` In fact, is equal to `this.setState({ a: 10 }); await undefined;` in the `test-03`. And `await undefined;` causes the code behind it to be executed in the next event loop.