# Is it correct to use await setState()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, setstate

my function looks like this:

```js
this.setState(prevState => ({
 time : prevState.time + 1
}), function() {
 doSomethingWithNewState(this.state.time)
})
```

is it correct to use await in this situation? like this:

```js
await this.setState(prevState => ({
 time : prevState.time + 1
}));
doSomethingWithNewState(this.state.time);
```

Comment: No. It's not right way to use await in front of `setstate` function. If you want do async operation, don it in separate thread and using the callback function update the `setstate` function.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47019199/why-does-async-await-work-with-react-setstate

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can't await `this.setState` for the reasons already stated. But you can write your own awaitable setState function easily:

```
promisedSetState = (newState) => new Promise(resolve => this.setState(newState, resolve));
```

now you can call

```
await promisedSetState({ someState: true });
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this with hooks? It would nice if someone could edit the answer. The new version of setState in hooks expects only 1 argument.

Comment: @josealvarez97 it's not necessary to await as you can just add a `useEffect` hook to react to state changes where the state variable is the hook dependency. Also if you think you must await for state change, then maybe you're doing something wrong. The thought paradigm of using hooks is completely different from the class lifecycle paradigm.

Comment: This only works with class components

Answer (score 23):

No `this.setState` doesn't return a promise.

So you can't use await in this case. You need to use the callback.

Comment: according to MDN, await expression can be used for "a Promise or any value to wait for. " https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: await doesn't work with a callback. You can test it.

Comment: @Anas await is working fine please check here https://next.plnkr.co/edit/0FqhaCGmtV0xkgAx?open=Hello.js&deferRun=1

Answer (score 5):

As the previous answer mentioned, `setState()` does not return a Promise, so you cannot use it with `await` as you intend. (Although you can `await` synchronous code as well).

When it's said that `setState()` is *asynchronous*, what's meant is that the *effect* of `setState()` may happen at a later time.

Furthermore, while reading `this.state` in the callback function will give you the state of the component at that particular moment in time when the callback gets executed, it's not *exactly* what you'd expect, because **all callback functions** are called *after* a batch of `setState()` calls gets executed. ([See this issue](https://github.com/reactjs/reactjs.org/issues/691)).

Comment: according to MDN, await expression can be used for "a Promise or any value to wait for. " https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant in the first sentence of my answer :-)

Answer (score 3):

Definitely not. You can pass a callback to the `setState` like this:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
 time : prevState.time + 1
}), 
() => doSomethingWithNewState(this.state.time));
```

Answer (score 2):

As David says, that promisedSetState function works great.

One thing to keep in mind, if you are destructuring your state in your function, do not use the destructured state as it is a const and won't change.

```
myFunction = () => {
const { someState } = this.state;
await promisedSetState({someState: someValue });
console.log(someState) <<<--- will be old value
console.log(this.state.someState) <<<--- will be new value
}
```

Answer (score -2):

`setState` takes a callback? Not sure why the first example would be an issue

https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296

Comment: Because callbacks are ugly