# Setstate not working propertly in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, setstate

I am relative new to ReactJS and I have some problems with setState.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import './index.js';

class Square extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        value: null,
        xNextPlayer: true
      };
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <button
          className="square"
          onClick={ async () => {
              console.log(this.state.xNextPlayer);
              if(this.state.xNextPlayer === true) {
                this.setState({value: 'X'});
              } else {
                this.setState({value: 'O'});
              }
              await this.setState({xNextPlayer: !this.state.xNextPlayer});
              console.log(this.state.xNextPlayer);
          }}
        >
          {this.state.value}
        </button>
      );
    }
  }

  class Board extends React.Component {
    renderSquare(i) {
      return <Square />;
    }

    render() {
      const status = 'Next player: X';

      return (
        <div>
          <div className="status">{status}</div>
          <div className="board-row">
            {this.renderSquare(0)}
            {this.renderSquare(1)}
            {this.renderSquare(2)}
          </div>
          <div className="board-row">
            {this.renderSquare(3)}
            {this.renderSquare(4)}
            {this.renderSquare(5)}
          </div>
          <div className="board-row">
            {this.renderSquare(6)}
            {this.renderSquare(7)}
            {this.renderSquare(8)}
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  class Game extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div className="game">
          <div className="game-board">
            <Board />
          </div>
          <div className="game-info">
            <div>{/* status */}</div>
            <ol>{/* TODO */}</ol>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  // ========================================

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Game />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
  **strong text**
```

The problem now is that xNextPlayer is not updated correctly. 
When I first click, xNextPlayer is true as it should. Then I want to set it to false. It does this correctly and console logs false. But when I click again, it is again set back to true. The first console log then is true, the second false.

But I want to store the value and be false.

Has anybody a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Look at this sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-paper-z8kpu . I copypasted your code (except I changed the initial value of a box to "U") and everything works as expected, and that is:

1. I click on a box with "U" - FIRST logs true and SECOND logs false
2. I click on another box with "U" - the same thing happens
3. I click on a box with "X" - FIRST logs false and SECOND logs true
4. I click on a box with "O" - FIRST logs true and SECOND logs false

You need to remember that each box has its own state, the fact that they are all the same component does not mean that they have a shared state.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, using async/await on the `setState` is not a good idea because [`setState` doesn't return a promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51968714/is-it-correct-to-use-await-setstate). You have to use the 2nd parameter of the [`setState` function](https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), which is the callback function (as a Promise), if you want to wait for the new state before updating your `xNextPlayer` value.

If you want to check your new `xNextPlayer` after updating it in your `setState`, get it back from the `console.log` in the callback scope.

```
this.setState({ xNextPlayer: !this.state.xNextPlayer }, () => { console.log(this.state.xNextPlayer) })`
```

Answer (score 0):

use this method.i think it will be works.

const handleClick =(xNextPlayerStatus:boolean)=>{

```
    if(xNextPlayerStatus){
     this.setState({value: 'X'})
    }
    else if(!xNextPlayerStatus){
    this.setState({value: 'O'})

    }}     



        <button className="square" onClick={()=>handleClick(this.state.xNextPlayer)}>
```