# Unable to set state value using useState in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I submit the info, the console.log gives me back a user.user.uid value. But when setting the value to a variable using useState, it sets the value as null and passes null value to userInfo function. userInfo is also an async function. Why is that?

```
  const handleSubmit = async (e, email, password) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const user = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
      console.log(user.user.uid);
      await setUserId(user.user.uid);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
    await userInfo(email, password, userId);
  };
```

Comment: state updates are async, the value after setting state is not available yet but after a re-render ...

Comment: What dependencies have you set in your `useEffect`?

Comment: @KcH When I call setUserId, doesn't it trigger a re-render thereby setting the state value since I have used await?

Comment: @Alien13 useEffect runs when auth state is changed, ie when a user is created and an id is set.

Comment: @vinDev await has no effect with setState, its async nature not the wait the promises are ..

Comment: Ah that explains it, as the first comment stated: state updates are async.

Answer (score 1):

If your `setUserId` state setter is not a promise (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58326822/15814542), you cannot await it.

This causes `await userInfo(..., userId)` to run with `userId` set to null.

You could

```
let userId = ...;
try{userId = ...}
await userInfo (email, password, userId);
setUserId(userId)
```

Comment: This works. But I would like to know if there is a way by setting the state.

Answer (score 0):

As the [state updates are maybe async](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) you could do it as

```
const handleSubmit = async (e, email, password) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  try {
    const user = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    setUserId(user.user.uid);
    await userInfo(email, password, user.user.uid); // pass uid directly as so
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```

If the result is not being used from `userInfo` using `await` is not required too ...