# Does aync await work with React setState method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

Can someone help clarify the use of async/await in React setState method? I thought it only work with Promises. I could not find any proper documentaton for this. Please someone help!

I have something like this in my app and it tends to work:

```
aync setNewName {
  this.setState({ name: "boo" });
  console.log(this.state); //prints most recent state - {name: 'boo'}
};
```

Why does it work? Did it work because in this case the state updated quicky before executing the console statement? Does it gurantee synchronous execution on other cases?

Comment: please paste code which you have tried so far?

Comment: I was reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47019199/why-does-async-await-work-with-react-setstate and still not sure how and why it works with setState @AvinashMahlawat

Comment: Where is the documentation?

Comment: "tends to work" is not a great barometer for working production code.

Answer (score 0):

This:

> clarify the use of async/await in React setState method

In the code provided, `async` is simply wrapping the call to `setState()`.

This:

> I thought it only work with Promises.

Assuming "it" means `async/await`, then this is true. What you don't realize is that the `setState()` function is being wrapped inside an Promise not *behaving* like a promise.

This:

> I have something like this in my app and it tends to work:

That code will **always** work. Why? because it simply executes synchronously. A Promised object is produced from the function call because it is declared as `async`.

This:

> Did it work because in this case the state updated quicky before
>   executing the console statement?

[EDIT]<del>No, this has nothing to do with *when the state gets updated*.</del>
It is most likely the case, yes. This code doesn't "wait for the `setState()` to finish, but it is finishing immediately is this case.

The way this works is:

1. Create a Promise
2. Execute `setState()`

   - which returns immediately [since it has not `return` statement](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/b87aabdfe1b7461e7331abb3601d9e6bb27544bc/packages/react/src/ReactBaseClasses.js)
   - React continues with state update process asynchronously - will complete in furture
3. Execute the console.log()
4. Resolve the Promise immediately (since there are no asynchronous operations

This:

> Does it gurantee synchronous execution on other cases?

No.

Comment: Documentation to what? [Async/Await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) OR React `setState()` [source code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/b87aabdfe1b7461e7331abb3601d9e6bb27544bc/packages/react/src/ReactBaseClasses.js) that shows `setState()` does NOT produce a Promise object.

Comment: @user117829 - Please see the [Edit ]

Answer (score -1):

Java script will execute all the synchronous code beforebit starts executing asynchronous code. The first console log is sync so it's executed.  Then setState is executed. As setState is asynchronous you can just treat it as promise which gets resolved when the state is actually set. await callback will execute once the state is set.  You can treat it as the promise was resolved.

Comment: _As setState is asynchronous you can just treat it as promise which gets resolved when the state is actually set._ - no, you cannot "treat it as a Promise". Here is the source code: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/b87aabdfe1b7461e7331abb3601d9e6bb27544bc/packages/react/src/ReactBaseClasses.js - as you see, there is no Promise here.

Comment: As I wrote you can treat it as a promise. I didn't mean it actually returns a promise. Even setTimeout doesn't return a promise but it's still asynchronous right?

Comment: You can't "treat setTimeout" as a promise either. That phrase "treat like a Promise"  has very distinct connotation.