# setstate is not working properly in react-native

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

so here i have 3 TouchableOpacities , for each press the backgroundColor changes its self and it works fine , so i tried adding in my changeColor() function a setState that returns a size (M,L or XL) of each TouchableOpacity pressed
here is my code :

```js
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
            colorId: 0,
            size:""
        };
    }
        changeColor = (id) => {      
        this.setState({ colorId: id });
        if (id == 1) {
            this.setState({ size: 'M' })
        }
        else if (id == 2) {
            this.setState({ size: 'XL' })
        }
        else {
            this.setState({ size: 'L' })
        }
        console.log("Button id:", id ,"size :", this.state.size)
    }
     render() {



        return (
                            
<TouchableOpacity style={this.state.colorId === 2 ? styles.button_XL_Colored : styles.button_XL} onPress={() => this.changeColor(2)} ><Text style={{ color: '#000000', alignSelf: 'center', marginTop: normalize(12), fontSize: normalize(20) }}>XL</Text></TouchableOpacity>
<TouchableOpacity style={this.state.colorId === 3 ? styles.button_L_Colored : styles.button_L}   onPress={() => this.changeColor(3)}><Text style={{ color: '#000000', alignSelf: 'center', marginTop: normalize(12), fontSize: normalize(20) }}>L</Text></TouchableOpacity>
<TouchableOpacity style={this.state.colorId === 1 ? styles.button_M_Colored : styles.button_M} onPress={() => this.changeColor(1)} ><Text style={{ color: '#000000', alignSelf: 'center', marginTop: normalize(12), fontSize: normalize(20) }}>M</Text></TouchableOpacity>
                    


        );
    }
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#F5F5F8',
    },

    button_M: {
        backgroundColor: '#FFFDFD',
        borderRadius: 10,
        width: normalize(50),
        height: normalize(50),
        alignSelf: 'center',
        marginLeft: 0,
        marginTop: normalize(-10)
    },
    button_L: {
        backgroundColor: '#FFFDFD',
        borderRadius: 10,
        width: normalize(50),
        height: normalize(50),
        alignSelf: 'center',
        marginLeft: normalize(140),
    },
    button_XL: {
        backgroundColor: '#FFFDFD',
        borderRadius: 10,
        width: normalize(50),
        height: normalize(50),
        alignSelf: 'center',
    },
    button_M_Colored: {
        backgroundColor: '#D05A0B',
        borderRadius: 10,
        width: normalize(50),
        height: normalize(50),
        alignSelf: 'center',
        marginLeft: 0,
        marginTop: normalize(-10)
    }, 

    button_XL_Colored: {
        backgroundColor: '#D05A0B',
        borderRadius: 10,
        width: normalize(50),
        height: normalize(50),
        alignSelf: 'center',
    },
    button_L_Colored: {
        backgroundColor: '#D05A0B',
        borderRadius: 10,
        width: normalize(50),
        height: normalize(50),
        alignSelf: 'center',
        marginLeft: normalize(140),
    },
```

The problem is i cannot get the size value that i wanted at first press
[image]

it should return size="M" when i press the TouchableOpacity thats has the M letter

its only working if it press twice :

[image]

the same case for other touchableOpacities :

[image]

Is there any solution for this ?

Comment: setState updates state asynchronously. Use the callback param if you want to log like that https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why calling react setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're using `console.log` right after `setState`, above results are expected because `setState` is asynchronous. So `console.log` is executed with old state instead of new state (new state has not been assigned yet).

You need to use the callback form of `setState` to get the right state.

```js
this.setState({ size: 'L' }, (state) => console.log("Button id:", id ,"size :",state.size))
```

You can read more about it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

// Added (I don't have enough rep to comment)

I saw John Lim's answer that suggests to use `await`, but `setState` does not return a `Promise`, so `await` won't work here. https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/0e100ed00fb52cfd107db1d1081ef18fe4b9167f/packages/react/src/ReactBaseClasses.js#L57-L66

Comment: Hi @moonlight8978, you are right! I have deleted my answer due to it is not the proper way to solve the problem, but async-await indeed did the trick. you may refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47019199/why-does-async-await-work-with-react-setstate

Comment: I have never heard about this trick before. Thanks @JohnLim

Answer (score 0):

console.log() does not show things immediately after useState().

One alternative might be putting console.log inside useEffect().

Another solution might be using setTimeOut() by calling the method after a certain moment.